# Git structure for project templates

Tags: git, gitlab

I'm trying to figure out a good structure for some projects that I'm doing where each project starts from the same base. The context of these projects are car models. In these projects there's a set of tools that is used in the projects and a part which will be project specific, like vehicle parameters.

At the moment use have created a repository for the tools and included those as a submodule. When I work on the tools I can easily update them in the projects via the submodule:

```
Data
include/tools <-- submodule
Vehicle_parameters
etc.
```

For the main project structure, I create a parent project with a branch `masterUpstream`. When I start a new project, I make a fork of this parent project into a child project and start a `master` branch. I register the parent project as `upstream`.

[image]

Sometimes I want to update the project structure, so I update the parent project and after this in the child projects I pull the `masterUpstream` from the parent project and rebase the childs `master` branch on the `masterUpstream`.

[image]

Is this a good way of working? If not, what could be improved? I feel like I'm using forks in a way they are maybe not meant to be.. Soon we will get some more colleagues and at the moment I'm the only one using this structure. Is this future proof?

I'm using Gitlab CE as a server for the repositories.

Comment: Why not just using branch ?

Comment: Because then the parent project will be cluttered with branches, suppose your 10 projects further it'll get messy right?

Comment: We have currently 1900 branches, and t is quite easy to work with them

Comment: That's really interesting,  i didn't know people used branches like that. Do you separate them with / to make categories?

Comment: yeap, and with use link to JIRA